# How to limit many group of checkbox selection according input element class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit checkbox input based on class of input element.

> class one-limit 2
>     class two-limit 4

My code could not limit the checkbox selection at all. So, i want to know correct way to do in JavaScript using input element class since i have many group.Previously, i add div for every group and set the class name same as input element class. It works. When i want to put in a table, i could not split the table row by div.So, i remove div.Without div, it did not work.

```
<table>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="2">Group A</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>HAJI </td> 
     <td><input class="one" id="2" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>SARA</td> 
     <td><input class="one" id="4" type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="2">Group B</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>LINA</td> 
     <td><input class="two" id="5" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>KUMAR</td> 
     <td><input class="two" id="7" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
```

function.js

```
var groupA=$(".one input[type='checkbox']");
 groupA.click(function()
 {
if (groupA.filter(":checked").length > 2)
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
  });

 var groupB=$(".two input[type='checkbox']");
 groupB.click(function()
 {
if (groupB.filter(":checked").length > 4)
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use [`<input type="radio">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) for groups of items where you only want to allow one selection? No js / jquery needed.

Comment: Radio button allow one selection per group. Some of the group need more than 1 selection. So, i prefer to use checkbox.

Comment: @benvc look like he want to handle multiple checked element (based on `if (groupB.filter(":checked").length > 4)`). Select multiple could be a solution: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp (Or a Bootstrap jQuery one: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what your after, try the below JS.

```
var groupA = $("input.one[type='checkbox']");
var groupB = $("input.two[type='checkbox']");

groupA.click(function(e) {
  if (groupA.filter(":checked").length > 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

groupB.click(function(e) {
  if (groupB.filter(":checked").length > 4) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Ive stopped people being able to tick by preventing the default action. You were also selecting the input incorrectly. You were looking for 'input type checkbox' inside class 'one'.

Comment: Hello Premlatha. Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpgj5twc/1/ please compare it to your code and let me know if this is the desired effect.

Comment: Sorry, this code works when run html and jquery in same file. when I put jquery in .js file and run. it does not run with effect.

Comment: The code works after i put inside $(document).ready(function(){     }). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah! Yes, any jQuery you want to use needs to be in the ready callback. No worries! Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code fixed and runnable.

First, your selectors were broken: `input[type='checkbox'].one` is the way to go.

Your version (`.one input[type='checkbox']`) selects all the input below inside a tag with class `one`, but with your DOM, the input has the class `one` so you must not add a space.

Next, just prevent the event to have an effect by using `preventDefault()` ;)

```js
var groupA=$("input[type='checkbox'].one");
groupA.click(function(e) {
  if (groupA.filter(":checked").length > 2)
      e.preventDefault();
  }
);

var groupB=$("input[type='checkbox'].two ");
groupB.click(function(e) {
  if (groupB.filter(":checked").length > 4)
    e.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="2">Group A</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>HAJI </td> 
     <td><input class="one" id="2" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>SARA</td> 
     <td><input class="one" id="4" type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>DAVID</td> 
     <td><input class="one" id="3" type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="2">Group B</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>LINA</td> 
     <td><input class="two" id="5" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>KUMAR</td> 
     <td><input class="two" id="7" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've added an entry to the first group, you can check it, you won't be able to check more than two checkboxes.

Comment: I have tried this code also. It gave desired result too.Thanks for your time. Both "input[type='checkbox'].one"  and "input.one[type='checkbox']" work well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attribute to create group.
Like this you don't have to update your HTML to create more groups:

(I also update your table to be more readable but the way you'll build your HTML didn't affect the JS (just use both `data-group` and `data-group-limit` attributes.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-group-limit]").each(function() {
    let group = $(this).data('group')
    let limit = $(this).data('group-limit')
    console.log("Init group " + group + " with limit of " + limit)

    $("[data-group="+group+"]:not([data-group-limit])").click(function(e) {
      if ($("[data-group="+group+"]:checked").length > limit) {
        console.log("Limit exceed for group " + group)
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="4" data-group="one" data-group-limit="2">Group A</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>HAJI <input data-group="one" id="2" type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td>SARA<input data-group="one" id="3" type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td>HAJI <input data-group="one" id="4" type="checkbox" /></td> 
     <td>SARA<input data-group="tow" id="5" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="6" data-group="two" data-group-limit="4">Group B</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>HAJI <input data-group="two" id="6" type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td>SARA<input data-group="two" id="7" type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td>HAJI <input data-group="two" id="8" type="checkbox" /></td> 
     <td>SARA<input data-group="two" id="9" type="checkbox" /></td> 
     <td>SARA<input data-group="two" id="10" type="checkbox" /></td> 
     <td>SARA<input data-group="two" id="11" type="checkbox" /></td> 
  </tr>
</table>



<table>
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" data-group="three" data-group-limit="1">Group C</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td>HAJI <input data-group="three" id="12" type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td>SARA<input data-group="three" id="13" type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could simplify the readability of what you are doing by aligning the name of the class with the selection limit you want for the group (if you have more than one group with the same selection limit, then you should apply a class to a parent element of the group so you can specify which group you are dealing with). Then, all you need to do is check the number of "checked" boxes in the group and use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the user from checking more than the limit. For example:

```js
$('.two').click((event) => {
  if ($('.two:checked').length > 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('No more than 2 checkboxes can be selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="two" id="apples" name="apples" value="apples">
<label for="apples">Apples</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="two" id="bananas" name="bananas" value="bananas">
<label for="bananas">Bananas</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="two" id="pears" name="pears" value="pears">
<label for="Pears">Pears</label>
```